# Neo4j: Cypher - counting number of nulls from list of columns

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a dynamic cypher, that reads something like this.

```
MATCH (n {company_id: 105, company_site_id:555,level:0})   
OPTIONAL MATCH(n1 {company_id:105, company_site_id:555,name:"price"}) 
OPTIONAL MATCH(n2 {company_id:105, company_site_id:555,name:"quote"})  
RETURN 
   n.company_id , 
   CASE WHEN n1.name IS NOT NULL THEN n1.name 
        WHEN n1.name IS  NULL THEN          
       'None'       
   END AS n1name, 
   n1.property, 
   CASE WHEN n2.name IS NOT NULL THEN n2.name 
        WHEN n2.name IS  NULL THEN 
       'None' 
   END AS n2name, 
   n2.property
```

Objective of cypher:

A dynamically built cypher that is used for validating existence of certain nodes. If the nodes exist, it returns the name else 'None'.

My requirement:

I wanted a means to check the total number columns whose value is 'None' .

In the above example I am having 2 columns/nodes (n1, n2), I need to get count of 'None'.

Would appreciate for any pointers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Don't you have labels on your company nodes? it should be way easier to do it with labels.

I think you should simply match the "null" part in your `Where` clause, then you just have to return a count():

```
MATCH (n {company_id: 105, company_site_id:555,level:0})
OPTIONAL MATCH(n1 {company_id:105, company_site_id:555,name:"price"})
WHERE
    n1.name is null 
WITH n1
OPTIONAL MATCH (n2 {company_id:105, company_site_id:555,name:"quote"})
WHERE
    n2.name is null
RETURN 
    count(n1) as n1s, count(n2) as n2s
```

With [Labels](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-node-labels.html), you can do it like this (assuming the label used is `Company`) :

```
Match (c:Company) 
WHERE c.name IS NULL
RETURN
    count(c)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your data model is really awkward?
Shouldn't your n1 and n2 connected to n via a relationship instead of duplicating all the data??

```
MATCH (n:Company {company_id: 105, company_site_id:555,level:0})   
OPTIONAL MATCH(n1:Company {company_id:105, company_site_id:555,name:"price"}) 
OPTIONAL MATCH(n2:Company {company_id:105, company_site_id:555,name:"quote"})  
RETURN 
   n.company_id , 
   coalesce(n1.name,'None') as n1name,
   n1.property, 
   coalesce(n2.name,'None') as n2name,
   n2.property
   sum(case n1.name when null then 1 else 0) + 
   sum(case n2.name when null then 1 else 0) as null_names
```